# Does $ABA=A$ have a solution $B$ iff $A$ has closed range?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I have shown that if $A$ is an operator on a Hilbert space with closed range then $ABA=A$ has a solution $B$ by using arguments similar to rank decomposition. I have a feeling that the converse is true. I'm trying to prove the contrapositive but I don't know how to utilize the fact that $A$ has a non closed range.

Comment: I love your profile picture so much

Comment: Thank you @TrystwithFreedom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y_n = Ax_n \to y$. Then $y_n = Ax_n = ABAx_n = ABy_n$, passing to the limit implies $y=ABy$, and $y$ is in range of $A$.

Comment: What a proof ! thank you Mr. @daw you are a genius